# Navbar won't close when I click anywhere outside it and have to click the close button to close it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've looked on Stack overflow but can't find a suitable answer that helps with my code. I have a navbar and it won't close when I click anywhere other than the dropdown menu options.

My app is broken down into several components, one of which is the navbar. The App.jsx code is below:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"

import { About, Contact, Experience, Hero, Navbar, Projects, Tech} from './components';

const App = () => {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="relative z-0 bg-black">
          <div className="bg-hero-pattern bg-cover bg-no-repeat bg-center">
            <Navbar/>
            <Hero/>
          </div>
          <About/>
          <Projects/>
          <Tech/>
          <Experience/>
          <div className="relative z-0">
            <Contact/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App
```

My code for the navbar is below:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { styles } from '../styles';
import { navLinks } from '../constants';
import { logo, menu, close } from '../assets';


const Navbar = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState('');
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  

  return (
    <nav
      className={`${styles.paddingX} w-full flex items-center py-5 fixed top-0 z-20 bg-navbar`}
    >
      <div className="w-full flex justify-between items-center max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        <Link 
          to="/" 
          className="flex items-center gap-2" 
          onClick={() => {
            setActive("");
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
          }}
        >
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" className="w-9 h-9 object-contain" />
          <p className="text-white-100 text-[18px] font-bold cursor-pointer"> I am a ---- &nbsp; <span className="text-[#8c0623]">|</span> &nbsp; Software Engineer</p>
        </Link>
    
        <div className="flex flex-1 justify-end items-center">
          <img src={toggle ? close : menu} alt="menu" className="w-[21px] h-[21px] object-contain cursor-pointer bg-black" onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}/>
          <div className={`${!toggle ? 'hidden' : 'flex' } p-6 black-gradient absolute top-20 right-0 mx-4 my-2 min-w[140px] z-10 rounded-xl`}>
            <ul className="list-none flex justify-end items-start flex-col gap-4">
              {navLinks.map((link) => (
                <li
                  key={link.id}
                  className={`${
                    active === link.title
                    ? "text-secondary"
                    : "text-white-100"
                  } hover:text-secondary font-poppins font-medium cursor-pointer text-[18px]`}
                  onClick={() => {
                    setToggle(!toggle)
                    setActive(link.title)
                  }}
                >
                  <a href={`#${link.id}`}>{link.title}</a>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Could someone help me with my ReactJS issue please?
I've also tried the solution in this YouTube vid (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxY3muW9ZOs) but it hasn't helped.

Comment: Hi Yogi, yes Tailwind CSS. The navbar has a dropdown menu with the various links of the website (about, contact etc.). When I click the menu to open it, it stays open no matter what or wherever I click (other links, other parts of the website). Only when I press the close button on the website it closes. I want to know a way that I can press anywhere else other than the close button and the dropdown menu closes if that makes sense? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to check for an **onBlur** event:

Try out something like:

```js
<div className="flex flex-1 justify-end items-center" onBlur={() => setToggle(false)}>
  <img src={toggle ? close : menu} alt="menu" className="w-[21px] h-[21px] object-contain cursor-pointer bg-black" onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}/>
```

Comment: Hi Ray, I tried this but unfortunately it doesn't work. I added the onBlur but it's of no use. Thanks for your input nonetheless 

Answer (score 0):

You can give your nav an id. After this, use the below code to capture outside click:

```
// on your App component    
const checkClick = (e) => {
  if(e.target.id !== '<your-nav-id>') {
    // code to hide nav
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('click', checkClick);

  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('click', checkClick);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Rohan, thanks for the answer. I tried putting the code you mentioned in the const Navbar section but nothing works. I gave an id="navbar" on the <nav> element I have in the navbar component but it doesn't work. Could you specify a bit more where I may have to go to do this please?

Comment: Can you tell where you have written the onClick method? I would suggest you to write it inside navbar component's parent component (App component).

The idea behind this is to identify target id and hide if target is not nav i.e., user has clicked outside nav.

Comment: I put the onClick method in the navbar code as shown above. I tried to write what you said in the App.jsx but it didn't work. I have the id="navbar" in the navbar component on the <nav> element. It is still not working unfortunately :/ Not sure if you have seen how my app is structured, the navbar and hero sections are within one div that are within the app file

Comment: You can try printing e.target.id and see what it prints when clicking different places.

Comment: I'm sorry I've never done that before. Could you provide more basic instructions please? I feel like I am very close to a solution.

Comment: So, on your checkClick method, you are getting 'e'. Inside this method, you can console.log(e.target.id). Now, try clicking in several places in your webpage like navbar, outside navbar and other places and see what it prints. You will notice that clicking on different places, prints different ids. Then, you can use the ids and close your navbar for all ids except navbar's id.

Comment: I have two onClick methods. One is for the opening and closing of the navbar, the other to set the active link and direct the user to the section. So are you suggesting to change my onClick to have one argument (e)? I tried writing the code for my nav where you said and nothing happens other than the code giving errors. Could you edit your answer with exactly how you think my onClick method should be please? Many thanks Rohan